# Unable to input any data in input field in selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys, excel-2021

Below is the element details of input field

```html
<input name="aadharNumber" placeholder="Enter Aadhaar No." error="[object Object]" maxlength="12" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
```

I have written following code

```vb
bot.FindElementByClass("form-control").SendKeys ("242730110592")
```

I have also tried using

```vb
bot.FindElementByname("aadharNumber").SendKeys ("242730110592")
```

Please help me in entering data in input field

Comment: Have you tried it without the parenthesis around the `SendKeys` argument?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Note the SendKeys method can use parentheses or without.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sbTest()
    Dim bchr As Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Set bchr = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    Dim Keys As New Selenium.Keys
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sUsername As String
    Dim sPassword As String
    sUsername = "myusername"
    sPassword = "mypassword"
    Call bchr.Start("chrome")
    bchr.Get ("https://www.wordpress.com")
    sbDelay (100000)
    bchr.Window.Maximize
    sbDelay (100000)
    bchr.SendKeys (Keys.Tab)
    bchr.SendKeys (Keys.Tab)
    bchr.SendKeys (Keys.Tab)
    bchr.SendKeys (Keys.Tab)
    bchr.SendKeys (Keys.Tab)
    bchr.SendKeys (Keys.Tab)
    bchr.SendKeys (Keys.Enter)
    sbDelay (100000)
    bchr.SendKeys sUsername
    bchr.SendKeys (Keys.Enter)
    sbDelay (100000)
    bchr.SendKeys sPassword
    bchr.SendKeys (Keys.Enter)
    sbDelay (100000)
    sbDelay (100000)
    sbDelay (100000)
    bchr.Quit
End Sub
Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay: DoEvents: Next i: End Sub
```